# Looking for a jQuery scrollbar plugin

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, maven-plugin

I'm looking for a scrollbar plugin for scrolling HTML content. I've tried several plugins like jQuery slider and jscrollpane. They're all suffering from the same problem: when keeping the mouse button clicked, move the mouse out of the browser window and back, then release the mouse button, the scrollbar still keeps scrolling.

Any ideas for a cross-browser solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an specific ones to recommend, but this page might be helpful: http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

**Edit:**

At least in Chrome, this plugin doesn't seem to suffer from the problem you described: http://www.simonbattersby.com/demos/vertical_scrollbar_demo.htm